# How to find index in a string format for a particular value in a column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

```
I have a dataframe named Top15 like this:  
Country              % Renewable Energy   Rank
Brazil               69.65                15
Canada               61.95                56
China                19.75                32
Germany              17.90                 2
Spain                37.97                11
France               17.02                12
United Kingdom       10.60                 5
India                14.97                10
Iran                  5.71                21
......                ......             .....

United States        11.57                38

Here i want to find the Country with greatest %Renewable Energy. 
Here country is the index of dataframe and hence i want the name of index only in string format.
But when i use the following code:
maximum=Top15['% Renewable'].max()
Top15[Top15['% Renewable']==maximum].index       (Method 1)
I get :Index(['Brazil'], dtype='object', name='Country')  

But when i use: Top15[Top15['% Renewable']==maximum].index[0] (Method 2)
I get:'Brazil'
```

So i am unable to understand that what is the meaning of index[0] here and how it is giving only the index in a string format(which i want as output) compared to method 1.
Also when i am using index[1] i am getting error: 
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Can somebody please clarify the meaning of index[0] here ?

Comment: It's just indexing `['hello'][0]` is `hello` that's it. You can set `Country` as index and use `df['% Renewable Energy'].idxmax()`--->`'Brazil'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling `.index` it returns you the index object, the only element of which, `'Brazil'`, is accessible via indexing the index object at position 0, so `.index[0]`.

When you are calling `.index[1]` you are trying to access the second element of the index object while it only contains one element, hence the error.

Comment: I got it.. Thanks for the clarification. @ Always Right Never Left